# azure jenkins pipeline can't push to registry

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline

So I got a docker registry ( azure container registry ) that has admin mode enabled & with passwords defined.

So basicly my console of the builder says following;:

```
Successfully tagged croc-hunter:latest
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker tag croc-hunter reponame.azurecr.io/croc-hunter:master-862fa81
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker push reponame.azurecr.io/croc-hunter:master-862fa81
The push refers to repository [reponame.azurecr.io/croc-hunter]
d99341ecd82c: Preparing
99e8e786d815: Preparing
7790d1ef8abe: Waiting
3a3beb3675ab: Waiting
99e8e786d815: Retrying in 5 seconds
d99341ecd82c: Retrying in 5 seconds
8c11d1b2af3f: Retrying in 5 seconds
unknown: The operation is disallowed.
```

here I login to docker registry:

```
withCredentials([[$class          : 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: config.container_repo.jenkins_creds_id,
                usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
  sh "docker login -u ${env.USERNAME} -p ${env.PASSWORD} ${config.container_repo.host}"
}
```

and jenkins says all good:

```
+ docker login -u **** -p **** ****.azurecr.io
Login Succeeded
```

I have even gone as far as creating a service-principle & hooked it into the jenkins script via ENV vars and execute it before docker login:

```
  container('az') {
  withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal(credentialsId: config.container_repo.azure_creds_id,
                      subscriptionIdVariable: 'SUBS_ID',
                      clientIdVariable: 'CLIENT_ID',
                      clientSecretVariable: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
                      tenantIdVariable: 'TENANT_ID')]) {
      sh 'az login --service-principal -u $CLIENT_ID -p $CLIENT_SECRET -t $TENANT_ID'
    }
  }
```

which results in this in console so its all good:

```
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "****",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "XXX Azure",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "****",
    "user": {
      "name": "****",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
```

BUT, this results in the same retrying errors....
What is the issue here?! To be noted, I can't push to my registry from my computer either by signing into `docker login -u -p -`. Getting the same retrying in x sec & then disallowed.

Can someone help me debug this? Ideally I want my registry to not be needed to auth via az cli, just via username & password.

Comment: Can i assume that use Kubernetes cluster ? if so your service pKubectl.exe create secret docker-registry secretacr1 --docker-server <acr name: for example  abc.azurecr.io> --docker-email <your email> --docker-username="<SP id>" --docker-password=$AcrSpSecret

Comment: Yes I'm using a kubernetes cluster. 

I just noticed it says Available in SKU: 0.0GiB in my registry on azure. Can it be that?? Any idea how I increase SKU storage?

Answer (score 1):

If the error shows as you provide that the Available in SKU: 0.0GiB for your ACR. It means that there no storage for you to push the image. So you need more storage for your ACR. Take a look at the information about [the limits of container image and storage for ACR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-storage#image-limits).

You can change the ACR SKU to which has the required maximum storage capacity like this:

```
az acr update --name myregistry --sku Premium
```

More details and some limitations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-skus#sku-feature-matrix), and you'd better pay attention to it. Hope this will help you.